# Getting Javascript type hinting in VSCode without importing, that would cause a circular dependency

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code, type-hinting

I have a situation where the class `A` creates instances of `B`, and sends itself as one of the parmeters. i.e.

a.js

```
import B from './b';
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.b = new B(this);
    }
}
```

b.js

```
class B {
    /**
     * @param {A} aInstance - The instance of A.
     */
    constructor(AInstance) {
        this.a = AInstance;
    }
}
```

I want to import A in b.js to get type hinting in VSCode,but that creates a circular dependency. Is there a way to get the type hinting without importing?

Answer (score 4):

Not easily in VS Code 1.22 which uses TypeScript 2.8 for IntelliSense. However TypeScript 2.9—which should be picked up in VS Code 1.24—adds support for type imports in jsdocs: `import('path/to/module')`:

`a.js`

```
import B from './b';
export class A {
    constructor() {
        this.b = new B(this);
    }
}
```

`b.js`

```
export class B {
    /**
     * @param {import('./a').A} aInstance - The instance of A.
     */
    constructor(AInstance) {
        this.a = AInstance;
    }
}
```